# react-final-form with multiple select

Tags: reactjs, select, react-final-form

I'm trying to build a form with a multiple value Select component by Material-UI using react-final-form. Somehow with single Select, I can get the value but with multiple, it doesn't. Somehow it seems like react-final-form is holding its own value internally.

Here's a the guiding link from Material-UI for building multiple Select:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sr6pf

I tried to replicate the very first example (without using react hook) in my form and I still miss something ?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-material-ui-example-jfmoe

What should I add to my  Component to make this work ?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe open an issue on final-form-material-ui? https://github.com/Deadly0/final-form-material-ui/issues/new

Comment: @ErikR. thanks for reminding, I did figured out the solution for my own question and it's quite odd, wondering should I add my own answer

Comment: Yes, I've lost count the number of times I've been helped by someone answering their own question. Do it, because someone will have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reasons I've managed to figure out the solution for my own question. The proper answer is to create a custom MultiSelect component instead of reusing the one from `final-form-material-ui`.

Notes: I've tried to use `<Select />` from `final-form-material-ui` but adding `multiple` prop to the component will not be passed to , this is weird.

So, my custom component would look like this, almost similar to the one from [their github](https://github.com/Deadly0/final-form-material-ui/blob/master/src/Select.tsx) with `multiple` prop added.

```js
import React from 'react';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

function SelectMulti({
  input: { name, value, onChange, ...restInput },
  meta,
  label,
  formControlProps,
  ...rest
}) {
  const showError =
    ((meta.submitError && !meta.dirtySinceLastSubmit) || meta.error) &&
    meta.touched;

  return (
    <FormControl {...formControlProps} error={showError}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor={name} shrink>
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        {...rest}
        multiple
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        inputProps={restInput}
      />
      {showError && (
        <FormHelperText>{meta.error || meta.submitError}</FormHelperText>
      )}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

SelectMulti.propTypes = {};

export default SelectMulti;
```

Hope this help someone in the future

Comment: This helped in my case, just one addition - changed `value={value}` to `value={value || []}` because otherwise it throwed an exception if the value is an empty string

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with by setting the `fomat` as such

```
<Field
 name="concepts"
 component={Select}
 displayEmpty={trie}
 multiple={true}
 value={[]}
 format={value => value || []}
 />
```

As per https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui/issues/212#issuecomment-358376925